# Synchronize execution of two functions

Tags: javascript

I have two functions and one of them is executed from another one. But second function don't wait execution first one.

```js
function first(){
  ... // some actions
  alert(1);
 }
function second(){
  first();
  alert(2);
 }
```

For example in this case if I use **second()** I see "2" firstly.
What can I did wrong and how can I synchronized execution of this functions?

Comment: What is all inside of `first`?

Comment: we will need more details, JavaScript execute functions in the order they are called, unless there is something asynchronous going on.

Comment: your example seems to work : http://jsfiddle.net/6683n0ud/

Comment: @tymeJV first contains code included AJAX call. Maybe it play some role?

Comment: Just for fun (I console.log rather than alert) http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/6683n0ud/1/

Comment: I would guess that AJAX call plays the entire role...

Comment: @tymeJV thanks, I found source of this promlem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Some actions*" from **first()** include the AJAX call. After it execution result  of this call is processed asynchronously, and control is passed back to the **second()**

Answer (score 1):

You could call the second function from the first one it's done it's stuff, i.e.

```
function first(){
  // do stuff
  second(); // call second function
}

function second(){
  // do more stuff
}

first();
```

Comment: why? I'm not calling the first function again? it's only called once

Comment: +1 This makes sense. Do not initialise the second function, but have it called inside the first function which is initialised.